# How to place clip art behind plotted data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to plot things on top of an image I insert into my figure. I'm not sure how to do that. Here is a simple example where I do my best to place scattered points in the foreground of [mario](https://art.pixilart.com/3aca029ec73badf.png): I specify the order with `zorder` and call the scatter command last. However, mario is in the foreground and the scattered points are in the background.

How can I make the scattered points appear in front of Mario?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

# load up mario
vortexRF = plt.imread('./mario.png')
imagebox = OffsetImage(vortexRF, zoom=0.08, zorder=1)

# initiate plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# place mario in plot
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0, 0), frameon=False)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.7, .42, 0.1, 0.1])
cbar_ax.add_artist(ab)
cbar_ax.axis('off')

# add scatter plot
NPoints = 1000
ax.scatter(np.random.random(NPoints), np.random.normal(0, 1, NPoints), s=3, c='purple', zorder=2)  

# comment that mario should be in the background
ax.set_title("we want the purple dots to be in front of Mario")

# save figure. Mario is behind the scattered points :(
plt.savefig('marioExample')
```

[image: Mario, please get out of the way of my data.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cbar_ax = fig.add_axes(..., zorder=-1)` arranges the z-order between axes. And `ax.set_facecolor('none')` makes the background of the scatter plot fully transparent (the default is opaque white, hiding everything behind it).

Note that everything that uses an ax is combined into one layer. An ax is either completely in front or completely to the back of another ax. Inside each ax, the elements can have their own z-orders.

To avoid copy-right issues, and to create a standalone example, the code below uses Ada Lovelace's image that comes with matplotlib.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

np.random.seed(1234)

# load up Ada's image
with cbook.get_sample_data('ada.png') as image_file:
    vortexRF = plt.imread(image_file)
imagebox = OffsetImage(vortexRF, zoom=0.2)

# initiate plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# place Ada in plot
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0, 0), frameon=False)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.6, .42, 0.3, 0.3], zorder=-1)
cbar_ax.add_artist(ab)
cbar_ax.axis('off')

# add scatter plot
ax.scatter(np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 5), 1000), .1),
           np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 5), 1000), .1),
           c=np.tile(['fuchsia', 'gold', 'coral', 'deepskyblue', 'chartreuse'], 1000),
           s=3, alpha=0.2)

# comment that Ada should be in the background
ax.set_title("we want the dots to be in front of Ada")

# make the background of the scatter plot fully transparent
ax.set_facecolor('none')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Note that you can also add the image on the same ax as the scatter using `imshow` with an `extent`. The `extent` is default expressed in the same data coordinates as the plot in the order `(x0, x1, y0, y1)`. This makes things somewhat simpler. The method using `fig.add_axes`, however, nicely keeps the original aspect ratio of the image.

```
ax.imshow(vortexRF, extent=[0.0, 0.4, 0.7, 1.1])
```